# Expand collapse text on a Wiki page

Tags: 2010, javascript, wiki

I am trying to have a section of text on a Wiki page hidden by default, but when clicking on a link/header the text is then unhidden/expanded.

I have searched online and thought I was getting somewhere, but SharePoint seems to be stripping out part of my code and stopping it working.

What I have tried:

- Added a CEWP to the bottom of the page. In it is a style tag containing hidden and unhidden references. Also, the CEWP contains the script which dynamically changes which style is applied to the div section.
- Edited the HTML in the Wiki page so that the section of text to be hidden/shown has a div id and refers to the CSS class.

  - Added code to the header which i want to be clicked on to show/hide the section: `<a href="#" onclick="unhide('DivID');">`

This seems to work fine when the Wiki page is still in edit mode. However, as soon as I save the page it strips out the `onclick="unhide('DivID');"` part for reasons unknown.

Does anyone have any idea on how to get around this? Or am I approaching this simple functionality in the wrong way? There's load of guides online about hiding/showing webparts, but what I am wanting to do is simply about doing this for blocks of text.

**Update**
It's still not working, but everyone's help is much apprecaited. I'm sure it's something silly i'm doing wrong, so any more pointers gratefully received. To clarify what i have tried so far:

- Added `class="display:none"` into the DIV tag for the text block that i want to show/hide.
- Added a CEWP to the bottom of the wiki page. This is linked to a text file stored on the site's library.
- This text file has the following code in it:
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try to place all the "behaviour" to javascript (should avoid inline handlers). Just add specific class to the trigger anchor and then in js write handler like something

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myTrigger")[0].onclick = function(){ unhide('DivID'); return false; }
```

Sharepoint page content editor is buggy in such things. I hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have removed the onlick part from the anchor tag, and replaced it with class="myTrigger". I have added your suggested code within the script taga in the CEWP. Not working though. Am i just to copy/paste your code into the the existing script tags? Or should they be encompassed by their own script tags?

Comment: First correction: don't muddle style="display:none" and class="someElementClass".
Second correction: You have 2 elements – a "trigger" anchor and a div (containing section of text). Also check whether you include jQuery library in your page. So handler will looks like $("#myAnchor").click(function() { … $("myDiv") … });
After saving the page check the resulting code (did SP cut your addings or not) with context menu 'View Page Code'

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make it happen using jQuery:

1. Whatever element you want to expand/collapse needs to have a display:none; in its CSS style.  Let's say you have a DIV:

Some cool text

1. Now its style should have the display:none in it:

   ```
   #myDiv { display:none; }
   ```
2. Using jQuery you can right a simple click event function

   ```
   $("#myDiv").click(function() {
   var isHidden = $("#myDiv:hidden");
   if (isHidden) {
       $("#myDiv").show();
   }
   else {
       $("#myDiv").hide();
   }
   });
   ```

At this point, that is all you need to show/hide the div.

You can easily add animation to it by simply adding one word:

```
$("#myDiv").show("slow");
```

Comment: This looks like just the ticket. I'm getting a bit stuck on how to implement it though. What do i do for step one to make sure that display:none; in its CSS style?

Comment: Look for the DIV where the text is located. If it doesn't have display:none you have to add it

Comment: Ok, i have added class="display:none" into the div tag for the section that i want to expand/collapse. Still not working. I will update the original question with everything i have done so far.

Comment: Someone asked a similar question on another thread. I used your answer. Just wanted to pass on my gratitude.